# Header not refreshed - Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files

Using Visual C++ 2012, without precompiled headers:

When I change a header file that is included in multiple files, the change is not taken into account when building.
If I rebuild all, the change is taken into account.

Reproduction case:

*include.h*

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_H_
#define INCLUDE_H_

class A {
public:
   A(int i) : i_(i) { }
   int i_;
};

class B {
public:
  B(int i = 1) : a_(i) { }
  A a_;
};

#endif INCLUDE_H_
```

*dummy.cpp*

```
#include "include.h"
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include.h"

int main(int, char**) {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.a_.i_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs 1.

Now I change `int i = 1` to `int i = 2` in *include.h*; I build and run, it outputs 1!
I *rebuild* and run, it outputs 2.

- The *dummy.cpp* file is necessary to reproduce the error. In real-life, this file is using *include.h* but not classes A and B (but this doesn't seem to change anything; declaring a class C with members A and B in *dummy.cpp* will still reproduce the problem). When removing the file *dummy.cpp*, or renaming it to *zdummy.cpp* (presumably it will be compiled after *main.cpp*), then the problem disappears.
- I tried with include guards, with pragma once, with both of them, with none of them, the problem is reproduced in each case.
- I cannot reproduce this problem with Code::Blocks/GCC; I didn't try with older versions of Visual Studio.

Am I missing something or is this really a bug in Visual Studio? If the latter, is there a known workaround? (Other than *re*-building at every step)

Comment: I assume you saved the changes before building (and/or enabled the "automatically save all files before building" option)?

Comment: Interestingly there is no such option in Visual Studio 2012.
I did make sure that my changes were saved before _buiding_ or _rebuilding all_.
I also just tried to not save before building or rebuilding, but it saves for me, since I can see the * at the right of the file name in the tab disappear.

Answer (score 3):

The header file must be part of the project. If it isn't the project will still build i.e. the compiler can find it, but Visual Studio won't track the date of the file.

Comment: The header file is part of the project.

Comment: @3li3, does that mean it shows up under "Header Files" in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yes, it does, and my reproduction project is created from scratch, I added all 3 files from within the project.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through such thing in the past.

Do you use precompiled headers? If you do please remove any project specific headers from the PCH. That is a lame mistake. Only place external, nonchanging headersin PCH, like C/C++ standard headers, Windows headers, Boost etc.

Comment: Well, telling the asker that they made a "lame mistake" is not very polite.

Comment: I do not use precompiled headers. I had the feeling that this could be the cause, but I did make sure several times that precompiled headers were out of the equation.

Comment: lol. I've done that in the past. It's not his fault. It will if he ever does that again :P PCH makes builds a lot faster but can be a pain in the a** when it is not right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan plus it is mentionned in the very first line of my question :D